# How to hook into Azure TableService Response in Azure Python Function?

Tags: python, error-handling, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm new to Python error handling.

Using Azure Table Storage as a config table for a Python Azure Function. To lookup a specific row in the table, I'm using the [table_service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cosmosdb-table/azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice.tableservice?view=azure-python#constructor) constructor.

```
from azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice import TableService
from azure.cosmosdb.table.models import Entity

TableName = "Table1"
PartitionKey = 'test'
RowKey = '123'

table_service.get_entity(TableName, PartitionKey, RowKey)
```

If an entity (row) is **not** found, the result is:

```
Client-Request-ID = 123-xzy 
Receiving Response: Server
Timestamp = Thu, 19 Nov 2020 20: 43: 23 GMT,
Server-Request-ID = xyz-123,
HTTP Status Code = 404,
Message = Not Found,
Headers = {
    'cache-control': 'no-cache', 
    'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 
    'content-type': 'application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8', 
    'server': 'Windows-Azure-Table/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0', 
    'x-ms-request-id': 'xxx-xxx', 
    'x-ms-version': '2018-03-28', 
    'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 
    'date': 'Thu, 19 Nov 2020 20:43:23 GMT'
}
```

**How do I use Python to access the `Not Found` message in the response?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from azure.common import AzureMissingResourceHttpError

try:
  table_service.get_entity(TableName, PartitionKey, RowKey)
except AzureMissingResourceHttpError as e:
  exception_content = e.args[0]
  print("===values you need===")
  print(exception_content[:exception_content.find("\n")])
  print("===all exception content===")
  print(e.status_code)
  print(exception_content)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is great. Thank you for the insights.

Comment: could you peek at **Edit 1:** above and guide the example? I'm not quite understanding how to take the exception output and control the `return`.

Comment: @ericOnline, thanks for your reply,as this issue has been closed, could you please open another question and let me know the link ? I'll reply you asap

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129992/how-to-handle-azure-python-function-exception-handling. Thanks for your continued assistance.

Comment: @ericOnline,welcome ,seems my colleague Hury has answered you : )