# How to handle Azure Python Function exception handling?

Tags: python, exception, azure-functions

I'm new to Python exception handling. How do I correctly `try` the following, `except` if `.get_entity` fails, but pass if `Status 200`?

**Here is where I'm at:**

- Its not correct though. Hoping you could elaborate with an example.

```
from azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice import TableService
from azure.cosmosdb.table.models import Entity
from azure.common import AzureMissingResourceHttpError

def get_table_row(TableName, PartitionKey, RowKey):
    try:
        table_lookup = table_service.get_entity(TableName, PartitionKey, RowKey)
    except AzureMissingResourceHttpError as e:
        logging.error(f'#### Status Code: {e.status_code} ####')
    finally:
        if e.status_code == 200:
            return table_lookup
        else:
            logging.error(f'#### Status Code: {e.status_code} ####')

data = get_table_row(TableName, PartitionKey, RowKey)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your code like below:

```
def get_table_row(TableName, PartitionKey, RowKey):
    try:
        table_lookup = table_service.get_entity(TableName, PartitionKey, RowKey)
    except AzureMissingResourceHttpError as e:
        if e.status_code == 200:
            return table_lookup
        else:
            logging.error(f'#### Status Code: {e.status_code} ####')
            return "whatever you want"
    else:
        return table_lookup
```

Comment: Thank you @HuryShen; testing this now.

Comment: This worked with one caveat, though a `Status 404` was received, the Function continued past this point. How do I gracefully exit the Function at this point if `get_table_row` does not return `Status 200`?

Comment: Hi @ericOnline In the code above, if got 404, it will execute the code under first `else`: `logging.error(.....`, `return "whatever you want"`. What data returned is up to you, but in my opinion, if you want to response gracefully, you can assign an empty list to `table_lookup` and then `return table_loopup` there.

Comment: Ok. So something like: If 404, under first `else:` add `table_lookup = None` and `return table_lookup`. Then when the function is called, `if table_lookup != None: "do things" else: logging.info("#### No entity found ####")`?

Comment: @ericOnline Yes